# Sonar unable to read my CPPUnit report

Tags: c++, xml, continuous-integration, sonarqube, cppunit

I try to integrate a CPPUnit Test cases in my Sonar, but when I put the report, there is a problem with the parsing.

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=test

# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=test

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=./core/

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.language=c++

sonar.cxx.xunit.reportPath=cppunit-report.xml

sonar.cxx.rats.reportPath=rats-report.xml

sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=cppcheck-report.xml
```

Then, here is the c++ code in order to generate my report of CPPUnit:

```
#include "PropositionalVariableTest.h"

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION( PropositionalVariableTest );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // informs test-listener about testresults
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult testresult;

    // register listener for collecting the test-results
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector collectedresults;
    testresult.addListener (&collectedresults);

    // register listener for per-test progress output
    CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;
    testresult.addListener (&progress);

    // insert test-suite at test-runner by registry
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner testrunner;
    testrunner.addTest (CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest ());
    testrunner.run(testresult);

    // output results in compiler-format
    CPPUNIT_NS::CompilerOutputter compileroutputter(&collectedresults, std::cerr);
    compileroutputter.write ();

    // Output XML for Jenkins CPPunit plugin
    ofstream xmlFileOut("../cppunit-report.xml");
    XmlOutputter xmlOut(&collectedresults, xmlFileOut);
    xmlOut.write();

    // return 0 if tests were successful
    return collectedresults.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Then, here is the report generated by this C++ code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<TestRun>
  <FailedTests></FailedTests>
  <SuccessfulTests>
    <Test id="1">
      <Name>PropositionalVariableTest::testInitCorrect</Name>
    </Test>
  </SuccessfulTests>
  <Statistics>
    <Tests>1</Tests>
    <FailuresTotal>0</FailuresTotal>
    <Errors>0</Errors>
    <Failures>0</Failures>
  </Statistics>
</TestRun>
```

And finally, here is what SonarQube answers when it reads this report:

```
INFO: Sensor CxxXunitSensor
INFO: Scanner found '1' report files
INFO: Parser will parse '1' report files
INFO: Processing report '/.../cppunit-report.xml'
ERROR: Cannot feed the data into SonarQube, details: 'javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[16,1]
Message: Can not call 'getAttributeValue(): cursor does not point to a valid node (curr event [null]; cursor state CLOSED)'
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 18.886s
INFO: Final Memory: 57M/364M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
```

My question is that I totally don't understand why it is like this... My guess is that it is about the fact that this report is in XML 1.0... :/
I managed to integrate CPPCheck, RATS without any problem, by also generating a XML report... But I don't manage it with CPPUnit

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: The parser is looking for a 16th line in your 15 line file... are you sure there's nothing weird in the file?   Have you regenerated it multiple times?

Comment: Also, I was able to run the XSL over the XML your provided and get reasonable results:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/0abe151386820b6d3dfcf2a760880f63637f3902/sonar-cxx-plugin/src/main/resources/xsl/cppunit-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl     http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output      =====>>>>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" tests="1" name="cppunit">
   <testcase classname="PropositionalVariableTest" name="testInitCorrect" time="0" />
</testsuite>

Comment: and your xml looks reasonably like their example XML, but maybe try plugging their sample in to your system and see if it works:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/0abe151386820b6d3dfcf2a760880f63637f3902/sonar-cxx-plugin/src/test/resources/org/sonar/plugins/cxx/reports-project/xunit-reports/cppunit-report.xml

Comment: I try to integrate their sample and I get : Cannot feed the data into SonarQube, details: 'javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[156,1]
Message: Can not call 'getAttributeValue(): cursor does not point to a valid node (curr event [null]; cursor state CLOSED)'... The same error but different row line...

Comment: I found the solution. It was just needed to transform into JUnit with https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/blob/master/sonar-cxx-plugin/src/main/resources/xsl/cppunit-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl.

If you could write the solution for me to give you the bounty because you were the only one trying to help me here :)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.   This kind of thing can be so very frustrating!

Comment: yeah definitely ... IT's like everything was done, the report was generated but impossible to graphically see the test coverage to see what is missing/weak...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we eventually found, the XML had to be transformed via some XSL to a different format which is provided on the site for the plugin here:

https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/blob/558a6c293a8bcd6434411f889957f938a6f2fb97/cxx-sensors/src/main/resources/xsl/cppunit-1.x-to-junit-1.0.xsl